# Options of mongoose save function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got an old nodeJs MongoDb project.
In the code the save function has as option:

`save({safe: {j: true}}, (e, o) => {})`

But "safe" is depreacted. It is indicated to use the option "w" with in the warning the link for more details (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save).
Unfortunately I do not have more details on the use of the w option. Could you guide me on this subject?

Knowing that I spent the afternoon looking for this information.

Many thanks in advance to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could simply do `save({"w": 1});` use 1/0 depending upon your requirement.

1: Requests acknowledgment that the write operation has propagated to the standalone mongod or the primary in a replica set

0: Requests no acknowledgment of the write operation. However, w: 0 may return information about socket exceptions and networking errors to the application.